# WooCommerce session

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, woocommerce

I have landing page out of my website, with subdomain is, lets say:

```
lp.test.com
```

On this page I have button "buy" that works great, with the link (example):

```
http://destination.com/?add-to-cart=10960&mobile=yes
```

When I click on this button, it take us to the destination.com cart and add the product to the cart - as I said - it works great.

What I want is to get the previous page url and display it on cart page.
I tried 2 ways: 
session and query string.

I see that WooCommerce is removing any query string so the url is just destination.com/cart, without the string after that.

So I tried sessions:

On the first page I have put on first line:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['previous_location'] = 'mobile';
?>
```

On the second (destination) page, I have put:

```
$previous_location = $_SESSION['previous_location'];
echo 'Session: '. $previous_location;
```

But also it didn't work. The echo is empty, it's printing only `'Session: '`.

My goal is to recognize if customer came to the cart from external landing page, if he does - I want to display other `get_header()` of my Wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(update)*

You need to use this code in your function.php file, to test if `session_start();` is not used yet by wordpress / woocommerce:

```
function registering_my_session() {
  if( !session_id() )
    session_start();
}
add_action('init', 'registering_my_session');
```

So you will only need on the second (destination) page:

```
<?php
echo 'Session: '. $_SESSION['previous_location'];
?>
```

This time you will get for `$previous_location;` ==> *mobile*

---

Another way could be **to use PHP cookies**.

On first page (at the beginning of your php document):

```
<?php setcookie('previous_location', 'mobile', time() + 365*24*3600), null
```

, null , false , true); ?>

on second page:

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE['previous_location']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! And i need to "end" the session on the first page?

Comment: you can use `session_destroy()` but if the user close the page or go to another page without `session_start();` the cession get destroyed herself

Comment: Because, i still get empty $previous_location

Comment: Yes. Possible that woocommerce erase any session except woocmmerce sessions ?

Comment: i have update my answer regarding sessions in wordpress… so what have you used. sessions or coockies?